# select mysql data with having sum

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i have table order_star_member which contain **users_id** as the buyer, **createdAt** as the time the buyer doing transaction, and **total_price_star_member** as the amount of transaction, i want to find the buyer from january with the transaction >= 600000 and the buyer from january who also doing transaction >= 600000 (both of this month doing transaction >= 600000) idk what is the exact query, so i make a new table called **january** which contain the buyer who doing transaction in january >= 600000 and **february** which contain the buyer who doing transaction in february >= 600000, after that i use this syntax :

```
select count(*) as total from (SELECT 
    sum(b.total_price_star_member) as total_transaction, b.users_id
FROM order_star_member b
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM january d
            WHERE d.buyer_id = b.users_id) AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM february a
            WHERE a.buyer_id = b.users_id) AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM order_star_member c
                WHERE c.users_id = b.users_id AND c.createdAt < '2020-01-01') group by b.users_id having sum(b.total_price_star_member) >= 600000 order by total_transaction) inner_query;
```

do you know what the exact query so i dont need to make new table again just like that.

**example table**

**January 2020**

```
 users_id        total_transaction

- 12                     750000
- 13                     450000
- 14                     300000
```

**february 2020**

```
users_id            total_transaction
- 12                        650000
- 13                        550000
- 14                        650000
```

so when i run the query, then the users_id 12 will appear because in february and january he/she had a total transaction in >= 600000

Comment: *i want to find the buyer from january with the transaction >= 600000* One sum for all years, totally?

Comment: nope, in january 600000 and in february 600000, both of month are transaction >= 600000

Comment: ... *in january 600000 and in february 600000* In january 600000 **for all years totally**? Or one specific year only?

Comment: Create a modelling fiddle and show desured result for this fiddle data.

Comment: example if im on january had a transaction total amount of 600000 and in february had a transaction total in 750000, then im on the list, but if im just transaction 600000 on only january / february, then im not gettin in list.

Comment: *example if im on january had a transaction total amount of 600000* 400000 in Jan 2018 and 200000 in Jan 2019 - it is "on January total 600000"?

Comment: no it isn't, this list are begin in december 2019 so january 2018 are not listed

Comment: But it will somewhen. And you will rewrite all your queries for to consider this???

Comment: no the data just made and started on december 2019, so january 2018 are not listed in this table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT users_id 
FROM order_star_member  
GROUP BY users_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'January' 
                THEN total_price_star_member END) >= 600000
   AND SUM(CASE WHEN MONTHNAME(createdAt) = 'February' 
                THEN total_price_star_member END) >= 600000;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=48daaaae52761efc2a0430820d57959a)

Comment: this was wrong, idk why but the result was 28 not 5 (the result of syntax when im make insert new table which is not effective)

Comment: can you please help me, idk why

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil A have already asked you: "Create a modelling fiddle and show desured result for this fiddle data" above. You don't want to do, why I am?

Comment: @FachryDzakyAl-QadriSabil The data which you add is NOT a fiddle. Look edited answer and the fiddle in it - you should have created at least what I did in the first block of code.